# TYPO3: pass table data from tt_address to fluid styled content element

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid-styled-content

I would like to output the data, from table `tt_address` in the database in an array and use it in my FluidStyledContent element. However, I only get an array with null.

in my `setup.typoscript` file in the Data Processing part i use this code

```
30 {
  table = tt_address
  as = myrecords
  dataProcessing {
    10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor
    10 {
        references.fieldName = image
    }
  }
}
```

It works with the table `tt_content` but not `tt_address`.

I try to create an array with all records that are stored under `tt_adress`.

Do I have to adjust anything for this?

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify, from which pid the address records should be fetched. A simple `SELECT * FROM tablename` is not possible.

`pidInList` needs to be added to your select query. By the way, what's the content type of the object `30`. I assume it's `CONTENT`.

Please check the [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/Functions/Select.html#pidinlist) for all the possibilities.

Hint: debugging database queries in TypoScript can be tedious work. To ease things I add a small typo e.g. to the table name. Then TYPO3 outputs the whole query in the frontend and you can spot easier what is wrong in your query.